# Hausdorffness of $\exp(X)$ implies regularity of $X$

Tags: general-topology

I have trouble proving this fact about the [exponential topology](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Exponential_topology)

> If $\exp(X)$ is Hausdorff and $X$ is T<sub>1</sub>, then $X$ is T<sub>3</sub>.

What I need to show is that if I have a (i.e. closed) $\{x\} \subset X$ and a (disjointly taken to this point) closed set $A \subset X$, then I can separate them disjointly by open sets.

Does anybody now how to do this and where I get my open sets for $A$ and $\{x\}$ from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make everything a bit more self-contained, I'll include the necessary definitions.

**Notation.** Let $X$ be a topological space.  By $2^X$ we denote the family of all *nonempty* closed subsets of $X$.<sup>1</sup>  Given $A_1 , \ldots , A_n \subseteq X$, we denote $$\langle A_1 , \ldots , A_n \rangle = \{ F \in 2^X : F \subseteq {\textstyle \bigcup_{i \leq n}} A_i, ( \forall i \leq n ) ( F \cap A_i \neq \varnothing ) \}.$$

**Definition.** Given a topological space, the *exponential topology* (or *Vietoris* topology) on $2^X$ is the topology generated by the base consisting of all sets of the form $\langle U_1 , \ldots , U_n \rangle$ where $U_1 , \ldots , U_n$ are open subsets of $X$. We denote by $\exp(X)$ the set $2^X$ under this topology.

<sup>1</sup><sub>We only include the *nonempty* closed subsets in this definition because $\varnothing$ causes problems.  In particular, $\varnothing$ would not be an element of any of the basic open sets to be described, and so the exponential topology will fail to be T$_1$, let alone Hausdorff.</sub>

---

Let $x \in X$ and let $F \subseteq X$ be a (nonempty) closed set not containing $x$.  Then $F \cup \{ x \}$ is a closed subset of $X$ which is distinct from $F$, and so by Hausdorffness of $\exp(X)$ there are disjoint (basic) open sets containing them, respectively. That is, there are open sets $U_1 , \ldots , U_k, V_1 , \ldots , V_\ell$ in $X$ such that

- $F \cup \{ x \} \in \langle U_1 , \ldots , U_k \rangle$;
- $F \in \langle V_1 , \ldots , V_\ell \rangle$;
- $\langle U_1 , \ldots , U_k \rangle \cap \langle V_1 , \ldots , V_\ell \rangle = \varnothing$.

It can be shown that $$U = {\textstyle \bigcap} \{ U_i : i \leq k, F \cap U_i = \varnothing \}$$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ which is disjoint from $$V = V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_\ell \supseteq F.$$