# What does it mean that the exponential topology of a space is T$_1$?

Tags: general-topology

If the [exponential topology](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Exponential_topology) $\exp(X)$ is $T_1$, does that mean that for every $x \in X$ we have that $\{x\}$ is closed in $\exp(X)$ or does that mean that $\{\{x\}\}$ is closed or does it mean something completely different? Unfortunately, this concept is rather confusing to me, so I would appreciate any kind of clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the definitions and notations from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/770941/8348).

Just recall two things:

- A topological space $Y$ is T<sub>1</sub> if $\{ y \}$ is closed in $Y$ for all $y \in Y$; and
- The points of the space $\exp (X)$ are the closed subsets of $X$.

Therefore $\exp(X)$ is T<sub>1</sub> if $\{ F \}$ is closed in $\exp(X)$ for each $F \in \exp(X)$, or rather, $\{ F \}$ is closed in $\exp(X)$ for each closed $F \subseteq X$.

If $X$ itself is T<sub>1</sub>, then $\exp(X)$ being T<sub>1</sub> would imply that $\{ \{ x \} \}$ is closed in $\exp(X)$ for each $x \in X$.

---

***Added.*** A fairly simply argument gives that $\exp(X)$ is T<sub>1</sub> whenever $X$ is.

> *sketch.* Assume $X$ is T<sub>1</sub>, and let $F,E \subseteq \exp(X)$ be distinct.  There are two cases:
>
> - If $F \not\subseteq E$, then $\langle X , X \setminus E \rangle$ is an open neighbourhood of $F$ in $\exp(X)$ not containing $E$.
> - If $E \not\subseteq F$, then pick $x \in E \setminus F$.  It follows that $\langle X \setminus \{ x \} \rangle$ is an open neighbourhood of $F$ in $\exp(X)$ not containing $E$.